# How do I import contacts from Data EXtension into Mobile Connect?

Tags: data, extension

I already have audience in Data Extension. I would like to send SMS to those audience, but I can't access Data Extension from Mobile Connect. I have been told that I can import Data Extension into Mobile Connect, but I can't find the feather in Mobile Connect.

Can somebody tell me how to import DE to Mobile Connect?